# get a list from : guild.fetch_members()

Tags: discord.py

I want to have a list of the members of a thread

When using :
`channel.send(str(await message.channel.fetch_members()))`

I get :

```
[<ThreadMember id=432287480599937024 thread_id=1185095420892958781 joined_at=datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 15, 5, 46, 6, 357000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)>, <ThreadMember id=1069317582559121419 thread_id=1185095420892958781 joined_at=datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 15, 5, 46, 7, 385000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)>]
```

How to convert this into a list ?

PS : I tried to do thread.members but it doesn't return anyone and according to the docs :

```
A list of thread members in this thread.

This requires Intents.members to be properly filled. Most of the time however, this data is not provided by the gateway and a call to fetch_members() is needed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `Member` object from a `ThreadMember` object using `Guild.get_member()`:

```py
# this is the list of thread members
thread_members = await message.channel.fetch_members()

# convert ThreadMember list to Member list
members = [message.guild.get_member(m.id) for m in thread_members]

text = "These are the members of the Thread:\n"
for member in thread_members:
    text += f"- {member.mention}\n"

await message.reply(text)
```

> Note: To use the [Guild.get_member()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member) method you need to activate the members intent.

Comment: I get "AttributeError: 'ThreadMember' object has no attribute 'mention'" when I run your code, what I'm looking for is a way to convert the ThreadMember object into a Member object

Comment: @Abraya ok, now I understand your purpose. I updated my answer